# PLSQL Check if varchar2 contains True

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I wrote a PLSQL Script which should check if one of the selected rows contains **TRUE**  if yes **then** he should print me a text.. but he fetches more than one row.

```
DECLARE

tmp varchar2(20);

BEGIN

Select Status into tmp 
From Cdb_Dv_Status;

    IF tmp = 'TRUE' THEN
    DBMS_Output.put_line('the output is false');
    ELSE
    DBMS_Output.put_line('the output is true');
    END IF;
end;
/
```

This is what i get when i select it with SQL

```
NAME                     STATUS         
-------------------      ----------- 
DV_ENABLE_STATUS           FALSE            
DV_APP_PROTECTION          NOT CONFIGURED       
DV_CONFIGURE_STATUS        FALSE            
DV_APP_PROTECTION          NOT CONFIGURED      
DV_ENABLE_STATUS           FALSE            
DV_CONFIGURE_STATUS        FALSE           
DV_APP_PROTECTION          NOT CONFIGURED      
DV_CONFIGURE_STATUS        FALSE            
DV_ENABLE_STATUS           FALSE           
DV_CONFIGURE_STATUS        FALSE            
DV_APP_PROTECTION          NOT CONFIGURED      
DV_ENABLE_STATUS           FALSE
```

this doesnt work either.. he tells me i have to **declare tmp**

```
    BEGIN
  for rec in (
    select status tmp
      from Cdb_Dv_Status
  )loop
    IF rec.tmp='TRUE' then
    dbms_output.put_line('Database Vault wird genutzt');
    end if;

   end loop;

    IF rec.tmp='TRUE' then 
        dbms_output.put_line('wird genutzt');

    ELSE 
    dbms_output.put_line('Database Vault wird nicht genutzt');

    END IF;

end;
/
```

Comment: Contains or is it equal ? It makes some difference...

Comment: What are you trying to do in the PL/SQL code? In the SQL query you get "true", "false" or other values, one for each row in the table. In the procedure you seem to want to select a single value into your variable - but the `SELECT` query will return a lot of values, not a single one. So the code can't be correct; but we can't help you fix it, if we don't even know what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: he should check the status where the return is .. "false", "not configured" if one of these is true he should return "true its used" else "not used"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get some **too_many_rows** or **no_data_found** exceptions depending on the data for the current case, rather prefer using a `COUNT` aggregation as in the following code block to check the existence

```
DECLARE
  tmp INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO tmp 
    FROM Cdb_Dv_Status
   WHERE Status = 'TRUE';

  IF tmp > 0 THEN
    DBMS_Output.put_line('the output is true');
  ELSE
    DBMS_Output.put_line('the output is false');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=757942db95eb4cad87ef50184008b34b)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for ur help but he skips the if tmp>0 and returns only the else statement 
In my case he sould return false but returns true
when i do it with a normal sql statement the return is "now Row selected"

Comment: This makes a huge (and unstated) assumption about what the OP's code is supposed to do. How do you (we) know that that's the OP's actual use case?

Comment: @Chicken2 it's as expected as your current data doesn't have any value TRUE for the concerned value

Comment: yeah but i changed the tmp>0 to tmp=0 doesnt work either

Comment: well, I confused the order of the false and true, now fixed them @Chicken2

Comment: Your query solves the following problem: "Print ***the output is true*** if the value 'TRUE' appears at least once in the `status` column." What in the original question suggests that that's what the OP was trying to do? Obviously his code doesn't do that, and I also don't see it in the explanation. I see "if one of the rows ..." - does that mean "at least one"? Does it mean "exactly one"? Does it mean "a specific one"? etc.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is to check if the value `'TRUE'` appears at least once in the column `STATUS` of table (or view) `CDB_DV_STATUS`, you can do something like this:

```
declare
  str varchar2(5);
begin
  select case when 'TRUE' in (select status from cdb_dv_status)
              then 'true' else 'false' end
    into str
    from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('The output is ' || str);
end;
/
```